# Xcode: Change type of view in storyboard scene

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, scene

I have designed views inside my `storyboard`. Inside one of my scene I want to change type of a view (which is a sort of container and have several childs) to another type e.g. `Vertical Stack View`.

1. I want to know is there any way to do that inside `Xcode UI`?
2. Is it possible to edit source code of scene manually like what I do inside Android Studio XML layout editor or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can embed all the child elements inside the container view to a
   vertical stack view using the option present in lower right corner
   of Xcode. Select all child elements and use the above mentioned option to embed it.

Please see the snapshot below.

[image]

2. After embedding, move the stack view outside of container view
3. Now, you can safely remove the container view without disturbing the
   stack view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. one more question: Is it safe to edit Scene source code manually and change type of View?

Comment: you mean, editing the storyboard file in text editor?

Comment: @VSB It is not safe

Comment: I totally agree with @RajeshKumarR.

Comment: And it is not possible to directly change type of View to another one?

Comment: @VSB, I don’t think it’s possible

Comment: @vsb, any updates on this? Is your issue got resolved?